# Does this random variable have a density?

Tags: probability, measure-theory, random-variables, brownian-motion

I have a persistent problem, which I'm almost certain can be answered using elementary probabilistic arguments, but for some reason I've been stuck for some time. Here is the problem.

Let $(B_s, s \in [0,1])$ be a fractional Brownian motion (here is the Wikipedia link for this process: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fractional_Brownian_motion). Consider the random variable:

$$Z = \int_0^1 B_s^4 \, ds.$$

Does $Z$ have a density? In other words, is the measure induced on $(\mathbb{R}, \mathcal{B}(\mathbb{R}))$ by $Z$ absolutley continuous?

Many thanks in advance for some thoughts or advice! :)

John

Comment: Is that possible to rewrite $Z$ in the framework of Malliavin calculus (c.f. David Nualart's book) then try to show $\| DZ \| _H > 0$ a.s.?. If so, one may conclude the absolute continuity by the Criterion of Bouleau and Hirsch, c.f. thm 2.1.3 therein.....

Answer (score 1):

Yes $Z$ has a density.
For each $s$ the random variable $B_s^4$ is a linear combination of Hermite polynomials of degree at most $4$.
Therefore the random variable
$$
I_n = \frac{1}{2^n} \sum_{i=1}^{2^n} B_{i/2^n}^4 - B_{(i-1)/2^n}^4
$$
is also is a finite sum of Wiener chaos.
Now $I_{n} \to Z$ in $L^2$ therefore $Z$ is also in a finite sum of chaos.
You can then you can use [a result of Shigekawa](https://projecteuclid.org/euclid.kjm/1250522278) to conclude.

But I would not be surprise if a simpler argument exists.